# session issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter sessions. When my user logged in session successfully store the data record that i want to store in it and also remove the particular record on the stage of logout. It works properly.

But the problem is when i print the all the data stored in session with the use of following code

```
$this->session->all_userdata();
```

It display two records one is stored during logged in and another is stored by default. If i check the same thing before logged in it show me a single record with some default values in session array. Like this:

```
Array ( [session_id] => c59388c6a8 [ip_address] => 230.230.230.230 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0 [last_activity] => 1420158230 [user_data] => [last_rec] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 30 [first_name] => Daniel [last_name] => james [user_email] => d@gmail.com [score] => 449 [picture] => images/301399704385.jpg [country] => USA [city] => na [userid] => d430 ) )
```

I dont know why session class return this same object with my session array variables.

Comment: When you load the session drivers it will create a session for the current user regardless of whether or not they are "logged in". Are you using any cookies?

Answer (score 0):

At the point of logout, unset all the userdata you have given individually and then destroy the session.

Use it like this.

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('id'); 
$this->session->unset_userdata('first_name');
$this->session->unset_userdata('last_name'); 

.....
```

and so on.

Then you use below code to destroy the session.

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

After that check and see if user data still exists.

Hope this helps.